# Exception handling in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code with multiple promise chain as shown below

```
.then(function(response) {
    //my code   
})
.then(function(app) {
    //my code
})
.then(function() {
    //my code   
})
```

Have added exception handling to each of them as shown below so that if one breaks the rest chain continues.

Is this the correct way of handling exception for multiple chain blocks, or any best practice can be followed to handle the exceptions so that the code execution doesn't break if one fails.

```
.then(function(response) {
    //my code   
})
.catch(e => {})

.then(function(app) {
    //my code
})
.catch(e => {})

.then(function() {
    //my code   
})
.catch(e => {})
```

Comment: Having a single `catch` handler at the end of the promise chain is common but doing what you have done is also fine if you know what you are doing. Each `catch` will catch and handle the promise rejection of the previously chained `then` method and what you return from the callback function of `catch` will be passed on to the callback function of next `then` method in the chain.

Comment: @Yousaf if a single catch is added  the next set of then blocks are not executed ,so followed this approach

Comment: Right. That's why I mentioned that it is fine if you know what you are doing. It is a reasonable way to allow the promise-chain to continue when there's a promise rejection in any of the stages in the promise-chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** your code can accommodate the error (whatever it is) that's occurring early on, this can be a reasonable way of doing it, but I'd always have to look twice at it in a code review because it's fairly unusual for the code to be able to just ignore errors like that. The code is roughly equivalent to:

```js
try {
    //my code   
} catch (e) {
}

try {
    //my code
} catch(e) {
}

try {
    //my code   
} catch(e) {
}
```

...but using promises instead. So it's a bit suspect, but *can* be correct, for the same reasons the above is a bit suspect but *can* be correct if you need to do a series of things, one at a time, and have each of them done even if the previous one fails.

Beware that it means `app` in the subsequent fulfillment handler will be `undefined`:

```
.then(function(response) {
    //my code   
})
.catch(e => {})

.then(function(app) { // <=== `app` is `undefined` here
    //my code
})
.catch(e => {})

.then(function() {
    //my code   
})
.catch(e => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538917/exception-handling-in-promise-chain#69539021) before, is correct.

I just want to insert my 2 cents.

You can have some fun with one helper function (or use something more fancy like whole `Either monad` thingy from `fp-ts` package)

```
const run = async (fn) => {
    try {
       const result = await fn()
       return [result, null]
    } catch (err) {
        return [null, err]
    }
}
```

and write code without `try\catch` or `.then\.catch`

```js
const [response, error] = await run(() => fetch('asdfasdf'))
const app = buildApp(response.ok ? await response.json() : { fallback: 'data' })

const [appResponse, appError] = await run(async () => {
  await app.compileTemplate()
  return app.buildResponse()
})

if (appResponse) {
 // ...
}
```

Or more useless approach, you can throw a custom error, so your first `.catch` block will be able to do something.

```js
class AppFromResponseError extends Error {
  constructor(message, fallbackApp) {
    super(message)
    this.name = "ResponseError"
    this.app = "fallbackApp"
  }
}

builder
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok !== true) 
      throw new AppFromResponseError('not ok', minimalApp)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    if (e.app) return e.app
  })
  .then(app => { /* some kind of app will be here */})
```